# linq grok'ed assumption check

Tags: linq

right if my head is correct.

LINQ is using similar syntax to SQL ie select from where join group +other functions.

There reason this works is due to the `<IEnumerable>` and you create a list [table] of things - a collection of things in which you can interregate

Is this correct or missed something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, that's part of it.

There are various aspects to LINQ:

- "Supporting features" in languages such as lambda expressions, anonymous types, extension methods etc. These aren't really part of LINQ, but LINQ depends on them.
- Language integration: query expressions in C# and VB are translated into normal code which usually uses extension methods
- LINQ to Objects: extension methods in `System.Linq.Enumerable` which use/produce `IEnumerable<T>` sequences of data
- Other LINQ providers (e.g. LINQ to SQL) most of which use `IQueryable<T>` and `System.Linq.Queryable`; these use expression trees instead of delegates to express the logic, so that the provider can translate the logic into the appropriate form for the data source